# On the asymptotic behavior of a sequence[Bulgaria MO 2024 Regional Round, 12,2]

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $N$ be a positive integer. The sequence $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ of non-negative reals is defined by $$x_n^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{x_ix_{n-i}}$$ for all positive integers $n>N$. We aim to prove that : $$x_{n}=\frac{\pi}{8}n+ o(n)$$

For this let $y_{n}:= \frac{x_{n}}{n}$. We have that :
$$y_{n}^{2}= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{y_{i}\cdot y_{n-i}} \sqrt{\frac{i}{n} \cdot \frac{n-i}{n}}~~(1)$$

We can notice from here that due to Rieman sum :
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{\frac{i}{n} \cdot \frac{n-i}{n}} ~~\to_{n \to +\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{x\cdot (1-x)} = \frac{\pi}{8}$$

Now we are left to prove that:

1. $(y_{n})$ converges
2. Taking the limit in $(1)$ lead to :
   $$\lim~~ y_{n} = \lim ~~\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{\frac{i}{n} \cdot \frac{n-i}{n}}=\frac{\pi}{8} $$

For this let $u_{n}:= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{\frac{i}{n} \cdot \frac{n-i}{n}}$ and $l=\lim u_{n}$. Consider $r_{n}=\frac{y_{n}}{l}$ we aim to prove that $\lim ~~r_{n}=1$.

For this we have from $(1)$ :

$$u_{n}\cdot \min\{y_{k} : k< n\} \leq y_{n}^{2}  \leq u_{n} \cdot \max\{y_{k}: k < n\}$$

But here I can find ways to conclude. Any help or reference if such exercice is standard would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest that you choose a better title. The current one is very uninformative.

Comment: Your sequence is undefined because there is no definition of x_1.  Does this mean that what you want to prove is a statement for all non-negative reals x_1 ?

Comment: @DanAsimov , we are looking at the asymptotic behaviour of the sequence.  Yes $x_{1}$ can be choosed arbitrary non-negative real.

Comment: even after proving $y_n$ converges to some finite $L$, it's not immediately you can just take limits of terms like $y_iy_{n-i}\to L^2.$ It may be true but its proof is definitely not just taking limit term-by-term.

Comment: Someone posted a discussion of this problem at https://dgrozev.wordpress.com/2024/02/14/growth-rate-of-a-sequence-bulgarian-2024-mo-regional-round/

Comment: @dezdichado: if $a_n\to a, b_n\to b$ then $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_ib_{n-i}\to ab$. However I am not sure whether this would help.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer that has been posted, uvw? and, have you had a look at the link I posted?

Comment: @GerryMyerson great page, but I don't get his argument about the sequence $(z_{n})$ converging to $1$,  he gave an intuitive argument but to formalise it as a correct proof doesn't seems straightforward.

Comment: @uvw and how about the answer that I wrote? Is it not clear?

Comment: @Kroki, thank you for you amazing contribution, I had to learn about some of the notation you used like $\inf_{n \geq 2}$ which I wasn't familiar with...  Now everything is clear thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x_1$ needs to be $>0$ otherwise $x_n = 0$.

---

Using AM-GM inequality you can prove that $x_n^2 \le \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x_k$ use induction and prove $x_n \le nx_1$ and $y_n$ is bounded.

---

Now let $\beta := \inf_{n\ge 2}\frac1{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{\frac{k}n\left(1 - \frac kn\right)} > 0$ choose $\alpha := \min \left\{x_1, \beta\right\}$. Use induction to prove that $y_n \ge \alpha$. Indeed, $y_1 = x_1 \ge \alpha$ and if $y_k\ge \alpha$ for $k\le n-1$ then,

\begin{align}
y^2_n &= \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{y_ky_{n-k}}\sqrt{\frac{k}n\left(1 - \frac kn\right)}\\
&\ge \alpha \times\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{\frac{k}n\left(1 - \frac kn\right)}\\
&\ge \alpha \beta \ge \alpha^2
\end{align}

---

Note $a:= \liminf_n y_n$ and $b := \limsup_n y_n$, $a >\alpha >0$.

Let $\epsilon >0$ and $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall n\ge N$, $$a - \epsilon \le y_n \le b + \epsilon.$$

Then for $n\ge 2N$

\begin{align}
y_n^2 &\ge\frac1n \sum_{i=N}^{n-N}\sqrt{y_iy_{n-i}}\sqrt{\frac in\left(1-\frac in\right)}\\
&\ge (a-\epsilon) \frac1n \sum_{i=N}^{n-N}\sqrt{\frac in\left(1-\frac in\right)}
\end{align}

Since $N$ is fixed, $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac1n \sum_{i=N}^{n-N}\sqrt{\frac in\left(1-\frac in\right)} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{\frac in\left(1-\frac in\right)} = \frac\pi8$$

So $$a^2 \ge \frac\pi8(a-\epsilon)$$ and this is true for all $\epsilon >0$ this proves that $a \ge \frac\pi8$. On the other hand, let $C = \max \left\{b+\epsilon, \max_{i\le N} y_i\right\}$

\begin{align}
y_n^2 &\le \frac Nn C + \frac1n\sum_{i=N}^{n-N} \sqrt{y_iy_{n-i}}\sqrt{\frac in\left(1-\frac in\right)}\\
&\le \frac {N}nC + (b+\epsilon) \frac1n\sum_{i=N}^{n-N} \sqrt{\frac in\left(1-\frac in\right)}
\end{align}

using the fact that $N$ is fixed and taking the $\limsup$, $$b^2 \le (b+\epsilon)\frac\pi8$$ and this is true for all $\epsilon >0$ so $b\le \frac\pi8$.

$$\frac\pi8 \le \liminf_n y_n \le \limsup_n y_n \le \frac\pi8$$ So $$\lim_n y_n = \frac\pi8$$